# vba - sum unique with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I would like to create a macro that will sum the unit column base by Product & DC. It will populate out the same product name, code with dc code and code without. Base on the code given I try to modify the code but fail when I added the column Sales Person in front,  Date & Country, as output I want to show the data with the latest date and country and the new data in the column.

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    
   ' Define constants.
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sFirstCellAddress As String = "A2"
    Const dName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "A1"
    
    ' Define workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Write values from Source Range to Data Array.
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Data As Variant
    With wb.Worksheets(sName).Range(sFirstCellAddress)
        LastRow = .Worksheet.Cells(.Worksheet.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row
        Data = .Resize(LastRow - .Row + 1, 8) 'modify
        
    End With
    
    ' Write unique values from Data Array to Unique Dictionary.
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    Dim arr(1 To 2) As Variant
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim cArr As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        Key = Data(r, 1)
        If Not IsError(Key) Then
            If Not dict.Exists(Key) Then
                dict.Add Key, arr
            End If
            If Data(r, 2) = 0 Then
                cArr = dict(Key)
                cArr(2) = cArr(2) + Data(r, 3)
                dict(Key) = cArr
            Else
                cArr = dict(Key)
                cArr(1) = cArr(1) + Data(r, 3)
                dict(Key) = cArr
            End If
        End If
        Key2 = Data(r, 4)
        Key3 = Data(r, 5)
        Key4 = Data(r, 6)
        Key5 = Data(r, 7)
        Key6 = Data(r, 8)
    Next r
    
    ' Write values from Unique Dictionary to Result Array.
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = dict.Count + 1
    Dim Result As Variant: ReDim Result(1 To rCount, 1 To 8) 'change from 3 to 8
    Result(1, 1) = "SalesPerson"
    Result(1, 2) = "Company"
    Result(1, 3) = "Product"
    Result(1, 4) = "Unit With DC Code"
    Result(1, 5) = "Unit Without DC Code"
    Result(1, 6) = "Date"
    Result(1, 7) = "Country"
    Result(1, 8) = "Grade"

    If rCount > 1 Then
        r = 1
        For Each Key In dict.Keys
            r = r + 1
            Result(r, 1) = Key1
            Result(r, 2) = Key2
            Result(r, 3) = Key3
            Result(r, 4) = CLng(dict(Key)(1))
            Result(r, 5) = CLng(dict(Key)(2))
            Result(r, 6) = Key4
            Result(r, 7) = Key5
            Result(r, 8) = Key6
        Next Key
    End If
    
    ' Write values from Result Array to Destination Range.
    With wb.Worksheets(dName).Range(dFirstCellAddress).Resize(, 5)
        .Resize(rCount).Value = Result
        ' Delete below.
        '.Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row - rCount + 1) _
            .Offset(rCount).ClearContents
    End With
    
MsgBox ("Done")

End Sub
```

| SalesPerson | Company | Product | DC | Unit | Date | Country | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JOHN | TPP | ABC |  | 2 | 12-Feb | MY | AA |
| JOHN | TPP | ABC | 1234 | 4 | 13-Feb | MY | AA |
| JOHN | TPP | ABC | 1234 | 4 | 14-Feb | US | AA |
| JOHN | PEN | DEF | 5678 | 2 | 12-Feb | US | AA |
| JOHN | PEN | DEF | 5678 | 2 | 18-Feb | MY | AA |
| JOHN | PKG | GHI | 9012 | 2 | 16-Feb | UK | AA |

I want to the output in another sheets as below:-

| SalesPerson | Company | Product | Unit with DC Code | Unit Without DC Code | Date | Country | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JOHN | TPP | ABC | 6 | 2 | 14-Feb | US | AA |
| JOHN | PEN | DEF | 4 |  | 18-Feb | MY | AA |
| JOHN | PKG | GHI | 2 |  | 16-Feb | UK | AA |

Comment: Why does first line show `6` for `Unit with DC Code` and not `8`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the dictionary key from the first 3 fields SalesPerson,Company,Product. I have concatenated them with tab character so they can be separated later for the results sheet.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Button1_Click()
 
   ' Define constants.
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sFirstCellAddress As String = "A2"
    Const dName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "A1"
    
    ' Define workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Write values from Source Range to Data Array.
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Data As Variant
    With wb.Worksheets(sName).Range(sFirstCellAddress)
        LastRow = .Worksheet.Cells(.Worksheet.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row
        Data = .Resize(LastRow - .Row + 1, 8) 'modify
    End With
    
    ' Write unique values from Data Array to Unique Dictionary.
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

    Dim arr(3) As Variant, Key As String, tmp As Variant
    Dim r As Long, i As Long

    For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        ' composite key SalesPerson,Company,Product
        Key = Data(r, 1) & vbTab & Data(r, 2) & vbTab & Data(r, 3)
        If Not IsError(Key) Then

            If Not dict.Exists(Key) Then
                dict.Add Key, Array(0, 0, r)
            End If

            i = 0
            If Len(Data(r, 4)) = 0 Then i = 1
             
            ' sum counts
            tmp = dict(Key)
            tmp(i) = tmp(i) + Data(r, 5)
            tmp(2) = r ' store last row
            dict(Key) = tmp

        End If
    Next r

    ' result
    Dim k As Variant, wsOut As Worksheet, rngOut As Range
    Set wsOut = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Set rngOut = wsOut.Range(dFirstCellAddress)
    rngOut.Resize(, 8) = Array("SalesPerson", "Company", "Product", "Unit With DC Code", _
                         "Unit Without DC Code", "Date", "Country", "Grade")
 
    For Each k In dict
        Set rngOut = rngOut.Offset(1, 0)

        tmp = Split(k, vbTab)
        rngOut.Offset(0, 0) = tmp(0)
        rngOut.Offset(0, 1) = tmp(1)
        rngOut.Offset(0, 2) = tmp(2)
        rngOut.Offset(0, 3) = dict(k)(0)
        rngOut.Offset(0, 4) = dict(k)(1)
        
        ' Date Country Grade
        r = dict(k)(2)
        rngOut.Offset(0, 5) = Data(r, 6)
        rngOut.Offset(0, 6) = Data(r, 7)
        rngOut.Offset(0, 7) = Data(r, 8)
    
    Next

    MsgBox "Done", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to a VBA solution (and I would probably use a dictionary with the SalesPerson as the key, and a class object containing the relevant information), I would suggest also looking at Power Query (available in Excel 2010+).

It may prove easier to maintain and modify once you get used to the language.

For the task at hand, you could start, for example, by

- select a cell in the data table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ UI opens, goto `Home => Advanced Editor`

  - Note the name of the table in line 2 of the code you see.
  - Then replace that code with the M-Code below, changing the table name to what your actual table name is.
- You should be able to figure out what is happening by going through the applied steps window in the UI, and also reading the annotations.
- To update, you merely `Refresh` the query. And you could program a button to do that.

**M Code** *edited and shortened*

```
let
    //change table name in next line to the real table name in your workbook
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,
        {{"SalesPerson", type text}, {"Company", type text}, {"Product", type text}, {"DC", Int64.Type},
         {"Unit", Int64.Type}, {"Date", type date}, {"Country", type text}, {"Grade", type text}}),

    //Group by SalesPerson, Company and Product
    //Extract the needed information
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"SalesPerson", "Company", "Product"}, 
            {
                {"Unit with DC Code",(t) => List.Sum(Table.Column(Table.SelectRows(t, each [DC] <> null),"Unit")), Int64.Type},
                {"Unit without DC Code", (t) => List.Sum(Table.Column(Table.SelectRows(t, each [DC] = null),"Unit")),Int64.Type},
                {"Date", each List.Max([Date]), type nullable date}, 
                {"Country", (t)=> Table.Column(Table.SelectRows(t, each [Date] = List.Max(Table.Column(t,"Date"))),"Country"){0},type text},
                {"Grade", (t)=> Table.Column(Table.SelectRows(t, each [Date] = List.Max(Table.Column(t,"Date"))),"Grade"){0}, type text}
             
             })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]